# Is credit card activity reported to credit bureaus when you carry zero balance at the end of each month?

Tags: united-states, credit-card, credit-report

I've read that it's important to continually demonstrate responsible activity with credit cards. If I pay my balance to zero each month, are the credit bureaus aware of my responsible activity or do I need to let a balance register on my statement before paying it off? My concern is that my behavior may result in it appearing as if I'm not utilizing these cards. I am located in the United States.

Comment: Where in the world are you? Credit scoring works differently in different places. Please comment or edit to add a location tag.

Comment: Yes. Closing until we get this detail. Otherwise we wind up with a US centric answer that may or may not apply to the OP.

Comment: @JTP-ApologisetoMonica OP has now specified the country.

Comment: @BenMiller-RememberMonica - thx for the alert, reopened.

Answer (score 3):

If you get your free credit report from each bureau each year, you'll see what balance your card is reporting.

Most cards report your balance to the credit bureaus once or twice a month.  If you are paying your bill on the due date every month, it is almost certain that the credit card will report a balance each time (the balance from the last statement + whatever new charges you've made since the statement date - whatever payments have posted) because you'll have new charges before payments post.  If you want to force a lower balance in order to reduce the percentage of your available credit you're utilizing which may improve your credit score, you can pay the balance early (including prior to getting the statement) on whatever day(s) the credit card company reports.  It is seldom the case that this is an effective use of your time but it might be if, say, you're applying for a mortgage with a credit score that hovers right around an important cutoff.

Note that credit reports are only a snapshot in time as well.  There is no history of balances.  So someone getting your credit report has no idea if you had a $0 balance every month for the last 24 months or if you had a $10,000 balance 24 months ago that you've steadily paid down to $0.  They only see that your current balance is $0 and that your payments have (or have not) been on time.  Unless you're actively applying for credit and close to a credit score cutoff, trying to manage what balance gets reported every month isn't beneficial.

Answer (score 0):

> I've read that it's important to continually demonstrate responsible activity with credit cards.

This is true, but it means "have a good payment history", not "show a balance". All of my lenders report a successful payment for the month even when I pay it off before the statement reports; I get both a payment logged and a $0 balance on the line.

> If I pay my balance to zero each month, are the credit bureaus aware of my responsible activity or do I need to let a balance register on my statement before paying it off?

You do not need to allow a balance to register, with a *minor* caveat:

Allowing a $1 balance to report on one card is called ["AZEO" - All Zero Except One](https://www.nytimes.com/wirecutter/money/what-is-credit-utilization/). It's the sort of thing you might do the month or two before applying for a new loan to maximize your score if it were borderline; it can be good for a couple extra points (anecdotally: 5-10) versus a $0 balance across the board.